# How to translate on Russian "towelheads"?

Tags: перевод

http://cryptome.org/2013/12/nsa-kills-rsa.htm

> Who think it is fine to destroy their own country's industry to get a
>   leg-up on a bunch of net cowboys and towelheads.

How shall be this translated verbatim on Russian?

Methinks, that this translated like, very stupid persons, with towels insted of brains in heads.

Or little bit easy:

[image]

Comment: You should avoid asking for straight translation requests on this forum. Update your question with what you think the translation is and why you think it's not correct - we can then try to help you.

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=define%3Atowelhead

Comment: Towelhead - "Тюрбаноголовые"?

Comment: Actually, though there are terms to describe "eastern" people in Russian, to Russian ear they don't have connection to such countries as Iran or Iraq and represent islamic culture. So, if you translate a towelhead as "чурка" you'll get the "migrant worker" instead of "islamic individual".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best explanation of the word I found was on [urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=towelhead):

> **Towel head**
>   A derogatory term for one of Middle Eastern descent, especially a male. It comes from their custom of wearing a turban.

I don't think there is a one-world translation of this word. You could follow @Artemix advice of *Тюрбаноголовые*, however I don't think it conveys the exact meaning.  You could also use longer phrase *с полотенцем на голове* (literally, *with towel on the head*) - however it's difficult to judge without further context.

Answer (score 4):

Для объяснения значения слова "towelheads” можно использовать сленговое выражение "чурка" или "чурбан". В американском варианте означает осокрбительное название человека из средней Азии, носящего тюрбан. В русском языке это значение не связано с головным убором.

Comment: Никогда не слышал что "чурбан" связано со словом "тюрбан". Чурбан это "бестолковый, глупый, черствый человек."

Comment: Чурбан не связано со словом тюрбан (разве, что по звучанию). Чурбанами иногда оскорбительно называют людей приехавших из кавказского региона. Именно поэтому данное слово можно использовать для объяснения, но отнюдь не для перевода "towelheads”. Спасибо за замечание, поправил пост.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, *полотенцеголовые*. But note that this is not an idiom, you would need to provide context so that people understand that you mean people of Middle Eastern descent.

In general, *something*головый means a person with *something* used for head. With the *something* being a non-intelligent object the word naturally implies that the person is stupid.

Answer (score 1):

we call em "чурбан" that's kind of mix of "тюрбан" Turban, that is exactly what you ask for and "чурка" that is a dumb person from the south...